# Не происходит возврата к основному фрагменту по нажатию на Up-кнопку

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

У меня есть активность с `Toolbar` и `FrameLayout` - контейнером для фрагментов. Навигация между фрагментами осуществляется с помощью Navigation Drawer из библиотеки совместимости (v7).

На тулбар есть кнопка-гамбургер, по нажатию на которую вылезает NavigationView - выбираем фрагмент - он сменяет основной фрагмент (`Fragment0`). Кнопка-гамбургер заменяется на Up-кнопку (стрелка влево). Мне хотелось бы, чтобы по нажатию на нее мы возвращались к первоначальному фрагменту, и чтобы боковая панель не вылезала по свайпу, когда нет кнопки-гамбургера. Но на деле Up-кнопка изменила только свой внешний вид, но не поведение - по нажатию на нее вылезает боковая панель.

Вот код моей активности:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String[] mNumberTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction
                .add( R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment0())
                .commit();
    }


    mNumberTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mNumberTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    initToolbar();


    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();


    // заменяем гамбургер на Up button во второстепенных фрагментах
    fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


            } else {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void initToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0 : fragment = new Fragment0();
            break;
        case 1 : fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case 2 : fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        default: fragment = new Fragment0();
            break;
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();

    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mNumberTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

private void setTitle(String title) {
    if (toolbar != null)
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: // it's for up button
            Log.d("!!!!!!!!!", "HOMe button is pressed");
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}
```

}

В метод `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` (`case android.R.id.home:` ) не попадаем при нажатии на Up-кнопку (в логе пусто).

Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помог метод класса `Toolbar` `setNavigationOnClickListener()`, который позволяет прослушивать нажатия на кнопку навигации, какой бы она вид не имела (гамбургер, стрелка или еще какой-то).

В коде активности пришлось изменить только слушатель изменения обратного стэка фрагментов:

```
    fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onBackPressed();
                        int fragmentBackStackCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
                        while ( fragmentBackStackCount> 0){
                            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                            fragmentBackStackCount--;
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в `initToolbar` добавить такое:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Даже гамбургер стрелочкой заменяться перестал.